# How to show frequently used commands in toolbars under the menu bar in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to show frequently used commands in toolbars under the menu bar in VScode?

In Visual Studio, frequently used commands are placed in some toolbars. We can click them easily with a mouse, not using keyboard shortcuts.

Is there a way to set up toolbars in VScode like Visual Studio?

Answer (score 8):

I made the extension just for this purpose.. you can add buttons like beautify, list files, undo, redo, save all etc to the editor menu bar in the VSCode. checkout
[Shortcut Menu Bar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerrygoyal.shortcut-menu-bar)

[image]

Comment: Somehow the number of displayed buttons seem sto be limited to 8 buttons, the rest of them beeing hidden under the `[...] ` menu. Is there a way to increase this number?

Answer (score 5):

No, this is currently not possible (VSCode doesn't have one built-in, and the extension API is rather limited when it comes to customizing UI). There was a feature request for this, but it was considered "out of scope":

[Support a real toolbar below the window title with actions (#18042)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18042)

---

Note that the extension API *does* allow you to customize the buttons shown in the upper right of editors, so that could be a workaround in the meantime:

[image]

The contribution point is the `editor/title` mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesmenus). This is how the built-in markdown extension adds the additional `Open preview to the Side` button for `.md files`:

[image]

The third-party [Markdown Shortcuts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mdickin.markdown-shortcuts) extension takes this even further, adding controls for editing such as `Toggle bold`, `Toggle italic` etc:

[image]